# zend framework, mysql: How do I Set name utf-8 in application.ini

Tags: mysql, zend-framework, utf-8

I have a zend application currently not displaying utf-8 encrypted special characters.

I need to use the command set name utf-8 for my mysql connection.
Col. Shrapnel hinted me with this:

```
$params = array(
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'username',
    'password' => 'password',
    'dbname' => 'dbname',
    'driver_options' => array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES UTF8;');
);
```

How do I get

```
'driver_options' => array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES UTF8;');
```

in my application.ini?

Comment: The comments on this blog post seem to have some hints http://www.zfsnippets.com/snippets/view/id/13 - `resources.db.params.charset = "utf8"` seems to be the ticket

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It was:

resources.db.params.charset = "utf8"

(Added in the config file)

Thanks to Col. Shrapnel again.

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
database.params.driver_options.PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND=SET NAMES UTF8;
```